# Xdebug 3 doesn't stop on breakpoints

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-3

I setted Xdebug extension and it's installed, I can see it on `phpinfo()` but it doesn't stop on the breakpoints and it doesn't write anything into `xdebug.log` file.

This is `php.ini` contents:

```ini
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = no
xdebug.client_port = 9003 
xdebug.client_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.log = "C:\xampp\tmp\xdebug\xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

And this is `launch.json` from VSCode:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense para saber los atributos posibles.
    // Mantenga el puntero para ver las descripciones de los existentes atributos.
    // Para más información, visite: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 0,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes"
            ],
            "env": {
                "XDEBUG_MODE": "debug,develop",
                "XDEBUG_CONFIG": "client_port=${port}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch Built-in web server",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-dxdebug.mode=debug",
                "-dxdebug.start_with_request=yes",
                "-S",
                "localhost:0"
            ],
            "program": "",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 9003,
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "pattern": "Development Server \\(http://localhost:([0-9]+)\\) started",
                "uriFormat": "http://localhost:%s",
                "action": "openExternally"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which of your three configurations you're using, but if you're using first the "Listen for Xdebug" one, then Xdebug won't attempt anything because you have `xdebug.start_with_request = no` in `php.ini`.

Set it to either `trigger` and use a [browser extension](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#browser-extensions), or `yes` to have Xdebug always initiate the request. Please refer to the [documentation](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug#activate_debugger) for more information.

The log is empty, because Xdebug never even attempted to make a connection to the VS Code plugin.